# How to open Outlook message from an external applicatin

Tags: outlook, ole

I would like to send a command from an external app to Outlook via OLE to open a particular message in the native viewer.  I have the EntryID of the message.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I have searched around and have been unable to find any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following (VB script) would do the job:

```
set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Applicatiobn")
set NS = App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
NS.Logon
set Msg = NS.GetItemFromID(YourEntryId)
Msg.Display(true)
```